# What is this place?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, avengers-infinity-war

After Thanos acquired the stones, completed the gauntlet and snapped his fingers he went to 'some place' where he met Gamora who asked if he had achieved what he wanted.

Similarly, in *Avengers: Endgame*, Tony too completes the gauntlet and snaps his fingers, and though it was it not shown in the movie there's a [deleted scene](https://www.hindustantimes.com/hollywood/avengers-endgame-deleted-scene-shows-iron-man-meet-his-daughter-after-death-watch-here/story-rQPdMXekP1Bh04p2hrDBeL.html) where he visits the same place albeit instead of Gamora he sees a grown up Morgan there.

What is this place, and why do the Snappers go to this place.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Blu-ray '*Maker's Audio Commentary*' (featuring the two directors;  Joe and Anthony Russo and the two writers; Christopher Markus and Stephen McFeely), Thanos is ***inside the Soul Stone***.

That being said, the directors also also offer the possibility that this might just be a "*fevered dream*" caused by the power of the Infinity Stones and the damage to Thanos' psyche.

> **Joe Russo:** ***So Thanos is transported, through the power that was
> needed, or required to wipe out half the life of the universe into
> this dream state inside the Soul Stone.***
>
> **Christopher Markus:** *And he is allowed one last meeting with that which he gave up to get there.*
>
> **Joe Russo:** *The spiritual representation of his daughter.*
>
> **Anthony Russo:** *It's a fever dream.*
>
> **Joe Russo:** *Yeah. Is it a fever dream? Is it a part of storytelling, is it plot? Does she exist inside that stone? Is this in his mind?*
>
> **Christopher Markus:** *The freedom you have when you've made 18 movies prior to this.*
>
> **Stephen McFeely:** *It's just so valuable for him as a character, though. In the next couple of minutes, he goes through some sort of palpable
> regret and then by the time he gets to the porch, I think he's...*
>
> **Christopher Markus:** *'Cause when your villain wins, I don't want evil cackling. I want to know the cost.*
>
> **Joe Russo:** *See there, with his gauntlet and the arm, the power that it takes to use all six stones is significant, and clearly damaged the
> gauntlet and damaged Thanos permanently.*